# How do I get the 'src' attribute from an image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I have the following HTML and I am trying to get the img src attribute:

```
<span id="firstSpan"><img src="https://mydomain.xyz/imgs/image.jpg" alt="Image Thumbnail" width="48px" height="62px"></span>
```

Here is how I am attempting to get the url after I have the current object pointing to `<img ...'` :

```
$(this).attr('src')
```

for some reason I get the 'undefined' value

Comment: that code looks fine, when are you calling it? Maybe $(this) is not the img tag.

Comment: What is your context, are you running this inside of an onclick or is this just right in the middle of nowhere ? (if that wre the case the value if this would be window whch does not have a src attribute)

Comment: try $('#firstSpan img').attr('src')

Comment: @IrkenInvaderl pretty sure $(this) is the img tag, because when I log to the console [console.log($(this).html()) i get back the img tag

Comment: If you get the img tag with `$(this).html()` then you are attempting to get the `src` attribute from the parent, not from the img. Try with `$(this).parent().attr('src')` and sure it works

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude is right, but you wouldn't select the `parent()`, the img is a child so it'd be `$(this).find("img").attr("src")`

Comment: Yes, sorry @RGraham , my mistake. I'm write with hurry up and i'm mistaken

Answer (score 3):

```
<span id="firstSpan"><img id='myimage'src="https://mydomain.xyz/imgs/image.jpg" alt="Image Thumbnail" width="48px" height="62px"></span>

 var value = document.getElementById('myimage').src;
```

Answer (score 2):

placing the code after the img element:

```
var src = jQuery('#firstSpan').children('img').attr('src');
```

before:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var src = jQuery('#firstSpan').children('img').attr('src');
})
```

For performance reasons, it could be better to assign a class or an id to the img tag and use it to get the element instead of the `children` function

Answer (score 0):

I suspect "this" is not actually targeting the image, but rather the span on click. Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="firstSpan"><img class="foo" 
src="https://mydomain.xyz/imgs/image.jpg" alt="Image Thumbnail" width="48px" height="62px"></span>
```

**JS:**

```
var source =  $(".foo").attr('src');
console.log(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#firstSpan img").attr("src");
});`.

You can also do `alert($("#firstSpan img").attr("src"))` or `console.log($("#firstSpan img").attr("src"))` to see if your code is actually being called as well, or debug it directly through your chosen browsers developments tools.

[Chrome Developer Tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

[Firefox Development Tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools)

[Internet Explorer/Edge Developer Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Safari Developer Tool](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)